# Using JDO with HRD on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, ancestor

To get consistent queries with HRD, we are told to use ancestor queries.

i am using JDO, however i cannot find an example of an ancestor query using JDO Query.

can someone tell me if its possible, and if so can you point me to an example?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do ancestor queries in JDO, only in the low-level API. If you have a choice of database frameworks, though, I would strongly recommend switching to Objectify.

If you must use JDO, you could add a 'parent' property to each child entity, which would allow you to query on the immediate parent of an entity.

Comment: This fact is not obviously mentioned anywhere in the documentation, as far as I could tell.  Considering ancestor queries are so important, I think it should be more prominently stated the JDO (and JPA?) don't support them.